# iTunes connect build not showing up for external testers

Tags: ios, app-store-connect

I want to send build for external testers.

I use Application loader to upload .ipa file.

I use Adhoc when export .ipa file.

But builds are not showing in TestFlight tab in iTunes-connect.

[image]

But its showing in 'prepare for submission' tab.
[image]

May i know what is wrong here?

Comment: Are you doing Ad Hoc export. Ad hoc export is for outside App store testing. If you want test it using testflight, use Save for iOS App store deployment option or you can directly upload from xcode.

Comment: You just need to export the ipa as a normal app store export. Adhoc is not for this. And FYI. If you want to send out a version for external users, it should go through a review as an app store version

Comment: @incmiko please answer same and i will accept it.
That solved my problem, i thought for external it should be Adhoc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to export the ipa as a normal app store export. Adhoc is not for this. And FYI. If you want to send out a version for external users, it should go through a review as an app store version.

Comment: can you tell me how much time it takes normally for beta review?

Comment: Actually I think it s around a day. This review act as a normal distributional review to the App Store, because of the security of apple. There is a portal if you may want to check the avarage review time. http://appreviewtimes.com Maybe it takes fewer days or hours than a standard review, but I'm not sure :)

Answer (score 1):

Are you doing Ad Hoc export. Ad hoc export is for outside App store testing. If you want test it using testflight, use Save for iOS App store deployment option or you can directly upload from xcode.